# Simple parser in haskell

Tags: haskell

I try to parse benncoded torrent file (part of my toy project to learn Haskell) into a dedicated structure in Haskell:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BC

data BEncode =  BString BC.ByteString
         | BInt Integer
         | BList [BEncode]
         | BDic [(BEncode, BEncode)]  <-- here is the problem I want to make it BDic [(BString, BEncode)]
         deriving (Eq,Show)
```

Everything works fine but I would like to make small improvement.
BDic data constructor takes (BEncode <- this is key, BEncode ,<- this is value) list. It's too general I would like to limit keys to be only BStrings, is there a way to do this?

Here is rest of the parser:

```
num::P.Parser String             
num = many1 digit

bInt::P.Parser BEncode
bInt = (BInt . read) <$> (char 'i' *> num <* char 'e') 

bString :: P.Parser BEncode
bString = do n <- num
         _ <- char ':'
         BString <$> (P.take (read n))

bList :: P.Parser BEncode
bList = (BList) <$> (char 'l' *> (many1 (bInt <|> bString <|> bList)) <* char 'e')                  


dicEntry :: P.Parser (BEncode, BEncode)
dicEntry = ((,)<$>bString <*> bencodeParser)

bDic :: P.Parser BEncode
bDic = BDic<$>((char 'd' *> many1 dicEntry <* char 'e'))               

bencodeParser :: P.Parser BEncode
bencodeParser = bInt <|> bString <|> bList <|> bDic
```

Answer (score 2):

> BDic data constructor takes (BEncode <- this is key, BEncode ,<- this
>   is value) list. It's too general I would like to limit keys to be only
>   BStrings, is there a way to do this?

One way to achieve this is by changing the structure:

```
data BStringT = BString BC.ByteString deriving (Eq, Show)

data BEncode =  BStringT
             | BInt Integer
             | BList [BEncode]
             | BDic [(BStringT, BEncode)]  
               deriving (Eq,Show)
```

This way you can enforce that it will be `BStringT` in it's first parameter.

Comment: Thx! I was looking for something like that, but I got another problem:  bList :: P.Parser BEncode function doesn't compile:                        Couldn't match expected type `BEncode' with actual type `BStringT'
    Expected type: attoparsec-0.11.1.0:Data.Attoparsec.Internal.Types.Parser
                     BC.ByteString BEncode
      Actual type: Parser BStringT
    In the second argument of `(<|>)', namely `bString'
    In the first argument of `(<|>)', namely `bInt <|> bString', I don't understand why...

Comment: Its the <|> function, it seems bInt<|>bString doesn't work anymore (inside bList, the same for bencodeParser function)

Comment: The first case of `BEncode` lacks a constructor.  It should be e.g. `data BEncode = BString BStringT | ...`